# Check for an incoming message in aws sqs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

How does my function continuously check for an incoming message? The following function exits, after receiving a message. Considering, long polling has been enabled for the queue how do I continuously check for a new message?

```
function checkMessage(){
    var params = {
                QueueUrl : Constant.QUEUE_URL,
                VisibilityTimeout: 0,
                WaitTimeSeconds: 0
            }
    sqs.receiveMessage(params,(err,data) => {
        if(data){
            console.log("%o",data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your function would need to continually poll Amazon SQS.

**Long Polling** will delay a response by up to 20 seconds if there are no messages available. If a message becomes available during that period, it will be immediately returned. If there is no message after 20 seconds, it returns without providing a message.

Therefore, your function would need to poll SQS again (perhaps doing something else in the meantime).

Comment: Should I be calling the same function in regular intervals?

Comment: Yes. Depending upon how quickly you need to process messages, you could call it very minute or even every five minutes. It's your choice.

Answer (score 3):

```
var processMessages = (function (err, data) {
    if (data.Messages) {

        for (i = 0; i < data.Messages.length; i++) {
            var message = data.Messages[i];
            var body = JSON.parse(message.Body);

            // process message
            // delete if successful
        }
    }
});

while (true) {
    sqs.receiveMessage({
        QueueUrl: sqsQueueUrl,
        MaxNumberOfMessages: 5, // how many messages to retrieve in a batch
        VisibilityTimeout: 60,  // how long until these messages are available to another consumer
        WaitTimeSeconds: 15     // how many seconds to wait for messages before continuing 
    }, processMessages);
}
```

Comment: Won't this engage the nodejs application in the loop forever?

Comment: It was meant as illustrative code to fully answer "how can I continuously check". In this case it would wait up to 15 seconds on each iteration. Naturally you could use a for loop with finite iterations if this works better for your use case. You might also prefer an Elastic Beanstalk worker to process your SQS messages: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html?shortFooter=true#worker-daemon

Answer (score 0):

`(function checkMessage(){
    var params = {
        QueueUrl : Constant.QUEUE_URL,
        VisibilityTimeout: 0,
        WaitTimeSeconds: 0
    }
    sqs.receiveMessage(params,(err,data) => {
        if(data){
            console.log("%o",data);
        }
        checkMessage()
   });
})()`

To continuously check for an incoming message in your aws sqs you will want to recusrsively call the aws sqs whenever a data is returned.

Comment: Please describe, what was the problem,  and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer